# How to delete record from Bigtable

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

I have datapipeline in dataflow; and am trying to delete record from bigtable using rowkey.
I tried couple of ways using; ex -

However am unable to successfully delete record, can i get some sample code if anyone has been successfully be able to perform delete using either dataflow or using java.

```
Delete d = new Delete(Bytes.toBytes(row_key));
listOfBatchDelete.add(d);
table.delete(listOfBatchDelete);
```

Answer (score 1):

try the following code, this will work

```
PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create();
BigtableOptions btOptions = options.as(BigtableOptions.class);
btOptions.setProjectId("your-project-id");
btOptions.setInstanceId("your-instance-id");

Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);


PCollection<String> rowKeys = p.apply(Create.of("row_key_1", "row_key_2", "row_key_3"));

rowKeys.apply(BigtableIO.write()
    .withBigtableOptions(btOptions)
    .withTableId("your-table-id")
    .withDeleteAll(true));

p.run();
```